# How to use simple-peer module in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc

I am new in Node.js platform and want to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-peer module in my application. But can not figure out how to implement that in my application. I can't figure out their documentation.  Is there any resource that can show the procedure of using that module with Node.js or Node+Express?

Comment: ? In the `usage` section of the link you provide, there is an example using nodejs....

Comment: I noticed it, but there are no routing and can't figure out how to use these code. It would be helpful for me if there is  a git repo that implements the module.

Comment: I am afraid that to get any help here, you will need to try something, show what you have tried and precisely explain what your problem is

Comment: The html file requires a 'bundle.js' file. I am confused where to get and put the 'bundle.js' file.

Comment: see response below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the documentation,

> This module works in the browser with browserify.

Basically you need to write `nodeJS` (i.e. commonJS) code - as shown in the examples - then using [browserify](http://browserify.org/), generate a bundle file which can be used browser side.

Most likely, [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) can be used as an alternative to browserify

Comment: with webpack you have to include this in config
```
plugins: [
    // fix "process is not defined" error:
    // (do "npm install process" before running the build)
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      process: 'process/browser',
    }),
  ]
```
and install the process module `npm i process --save`

Answer (score 5):

**Might be late but :**

If you do not want to, it's not compulsory to use `browserify` or `webpack` for this very module to work, but is a good practice though, atleast for now.

In [simple-peer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-peer) package it is mentioned :

> Note: If you're NOT using browserify, then use the included standalone file simplepeer.min.js. This exports a SimplePeer constructor on window.

This means you can get `SimplePeer()` on the `window` object by adding a `script` tag in your `html` file like :

```
<script src="<path to your node_modules>/simple-peer/simplepeer.min.js"></script>
```

For me this works :

```
<script src="<path to your node_modules>/simple-peer/simplepeer.min.js"></script>
<script src="/index.js"></script>   <!-- Keep this script tag below simplepeer.min.js-->
```

Now use `SimplePeer()` inside `index.html` as :

```
const peer = new SimplePeer({
    // Code ...
});
```

Hope this helps :)